# .htaccess is adding www. to URL with site cannot be reached with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have set up a .htaccess to Rewrite the homepage of my site to /web/index.php and it seems to work fine ,however when I want to go to /web/about.php it seems to add a www. to the URL and I get a Site cannot be reached in my browser.

I either want to allow the www. to work or just remove it. The former would be better.

in my .htaccess I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.ddns.net/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^$ /web/index.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^about /web/about.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I am relatively new to this and not 100% sure how it all works but I know that it should Rewrite /web/about.php to just /about in the URL, which it does. But it also add www. to the front of the URL and breaks the page. As I said it loads fine on the homepage but not on /about

I imagine the problem probably lies at that RewriteCond part and the RewriteRule below it?

Any help would be much appreciated, also please let me know if I haven't given enough information.

Thank you!

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache. There is no rule here that will add `www`

Comment: Whelp... Yep thats it. Cleared cache and all is fine. Now I feel stupid. Thank you for your help! Can't believe it was so simple!